# Great common divisor with loops

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop, greatest-common-divisor

I think my logic is wrong but I can't understand where I am making a mistake. I am trying to find the great common divisor, and code will determine what to do if a is bigger than b or b is bigger than a.

I tried many loops, if, while but in the end I deleted all to clear my sight. I made flowchart however it is not coming along with my code.

```
var a = 64;
var b = 12;
var newA;

while(a > b && newA != 0){

    newA = a - b;

    if(newA === 0){

        outputObj.innerHTML = outputObj.innerHTML + "GCD is " + b;
    }
}



    while(a < b && newA != 0){

        newA = b - a;
    }

    if(newA === 0){

        outputObj.innerHTML = outputObj.innerHTML + "GCD is " + a;

    }
  }
```

If a is 64 and b is 12 the GCD is 4, if a is 35 and b is 42 the GCD is 7

Comment: there's some nice algorithms at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different problems here. This looks like [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), so I'll try to point you in the right direction for a couple of the problems rather than e.g. telling you exactly what your code should say.

- In your loops, you never update the value of either `a` or `b`.
- Pretending that that's fixed, your code will either subtract `a` from `b` several times or subtract `b` from `a` lots of times. Doing that computes *the remainder on dividing one number by the other*, not *the greatest common divisor*.

  - I'm betting that you've been given a description of an algorithm for computing the greatest common divisor. Read through it again, comparing what it does against what your code does.

Here's a powerful method for finding problems in this sort of code: try to *run it in your head*, pretending that you're the computer. Go through, step by step, doing what the computer will do. With your code above, it might begin like this:

- OK, I've got variables called `a` and `b`, whose values are 64 and 12. And a variable called `newA`, whose value hasn't been specified yet.
- Now I need to check whether `a` is bigger than `b` -- yup, it is -- and then whether `newA` is zero.

  - Wait, I haven't given `newA` a value at this point. (**You've found a bug** here. Let's pretend it's fixed and move on.)
- Now I set `newA` to be `a-b`, which is 52.
- Now I check whether `newA` is zero, which it isn't so I don't need to do the stuff inside the `if` block there.
- OK, so we've done one iteration of the `while` loop. Back to the start of the loop.
- Now I need to check whether `a` is bigger than `b` -- yup, it is -- and then whether `newA` is zero.

  - Wait a minute, I'm checking the exact same thing as last time: nothing's changed. How's this loop going to end? (**You've found another bug** here.)

And so on.